# Second derivative of an inequality

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Assuming there exists $Q$ greater than or equal to $0$
$$|f'(a+b) - f'(a)| < Q|b|$$

How would I differentiate the above with respect to b? And is that operation allowed?

Answer (score 0):

You can't generally "differentiate an inequality". That is, if you know that $$f(x) < g(x)$$ in some interval, you **CANNOT** conclude that $$f'(x) < g'(x).$$

But you can "take the limit of an inequality". That is, if you know that $$f(x) < K$$ on some interval, where $K$ is a constant, then if $a$ is a point in that interval you can conclude that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) \le K, $$ assuming you know that the limit exists.

Will that help you?